# Draw two lines but I need one

Tags: svg

make an SVG draw line but it draws 2 lines when I need only one? Can someone fix it, please?

```html
<style>
  .st1 {
    fill: none;
    stroke: black;
    stroke-width: 2px;
    stroke-miterlimit: 5;
  }

  .st1 {
    stroke-dasharray: 3904;
    stroke-dashoffset: 3904;
    animation: dash 3s linear forwards;
  }

  @keyframes dash {
    from {
      stroke-dashoffset: 3904;
    }

    to {
      stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    }
  }
</style>
<svg class="about__line" width="968" height="548" viewBox="0 0 968 548" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path class="st1" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M796.532 372.979L811.112 507.247L829.562 523.554H935.568L947.75 531.969H968V536.778H946.345L934.163 528.363H827.852L808.189 510.983C808.038 510.912 807.915 510.836 807.824 510.776C807.799 510.76 807.777 510.745 807.757 510.732C807.697 510.692 807.659 510.667 807.645 510.667C807.259 510.367 807.066 509.887 807.001 509.406L791.898 372.499C791.833 371.958 792.026 371.358 792.412 370.998L799.042 363.915H793.314C792.155 363.915 791.19 363.015 791.19 361.935V350.05L684.403 348.009C683.438 348.009 682.601 347.409 682.344 346.569L680.091 338.946C679.962 338.466 680.026 337.986 680.22 337.506L689.102 321.059C688.716 320.159 688.652 318.839 688.974 316.738C687.107 316.558 683.631 316.558 680.22 316.618H680.155C678.997 316.618 678.095 315.837 677.967 314.817L677.387 308.635L675.135 308.815C674.491 308.875 673.911 308.695 673.525 308.335C673.075 307.975 672.817 307.434 672.817 306.894L672.431 280.544C672.431 280.424 672.431 280.304 672.495 280.184L673.976 272.081L669.663 266.439C669.213 265.839 669.148 265.119 669.47 264.458C669.792 263.798 670.436 263.378 671.208 263.318L678.417 262.658L679.962 261.037L669.985 253.114C669.341 252.574 669.084 251.854 669.277 251.133L669.792 249.213L659.751 239.249C659.622 239.129 659.493 239.009 659.429 238.889L649.838 224.123C649.645 223.823 649.581 223.523 649.516 223.163L649.13 211.639L645.397 202.815H644.045C642.886 202.815 641.985 201.975 641.856 200.955C641.856 200.835 641.084 188.95 637.994 181.928C637.479 180.667 637.029 179.947 636.707 179.527C636.321 180.247 635.484 180.667 634.647 180.607C633.746 180.547 632.909 179.887 632.716 179.047C632.716 179.047 632.716 178.987 632.652 178.867L632.576 178.59C631.592 174.979 628.656 164.213 626.086 159.479C623.318 154.317 598.279 130.008 578.776 123.346C577.875 123.046 577.296 122.205 577.36 121.365L578.197 108.76C578.132 108.04 577.682 104.139 573.562 101.678C572.919 101.318 572.597 100.657 572.597 99.9972V80.3099C572.597 79.5296 573.112 78.8093 573.82 78.5092H573.884C574.077 78.4492 574.978 77.969 575.236 77.1887C575.429 76.7085 575.3 76.1083 574.85 75.388L572.468 71.3065C572.275 71.0064 572.211 70.6463 572.211 70.3462V61.2228C571.631 60.8026 571.116 60.5625 570.859 60.4425V60.5025C569.893 63.5036 570.086 68.7856 570.151 69.806C570.215 70.5863 569.765 71.3065 569.057 71.7267C568.284 72.0868 567.383 72.0268 566.739 71.5466L559.144 66.3847C558.371 65.9045 558.114 65.0042 558.371 64.2239L558.38 64.187C558.479 63.7416 559.088 61.0154 557.406 58.4017C554.96 54.6203 551.935 20.1675 551.098 9.6636C551.034 9.30346 551.162 8.94333 551.291 8.64322C551.613 8.04299 552.321 6.1823 551.806 5.04188C551.613 4.62172 551.162 4.32161 550.519 4.08152H549.231C548.523 4.32161 548.137 4.62172 547.944 5.04188C547.429 6.1823 548.137 8.04299 548.459 8.64322C548.652 8.94333 548.716 9.30346 548.652 9.6636C547.558 23.1086 544.726 54.7404 542.344 58.4017C540.477 61.2228 541.378 64.2239 541.378 64.2239C541.636 65.0042 541.314 65.9045 540.606 66.3847L532.946 71.6066C532.303 72.0868 531.401 72.1468 530.629 71.7867C529.857 71.4266 529.47 70.6463 529.535 69.926C529.599 68.8456 529.792 63.6237 528.827 60.6226V60.5025C528.798 60.5159 528.765 60.5309 528.729 60.5474C528.44 60.6785 527.932 60.9096 527.475 61.2828V70.2261C527.475 70.5863 527.411 70.8864 527.217 71.1865L524.772 75.268C524.385 75.9883 524.257 76.5885 524.385 77.1287C524.707 77.909 525.737 78.4492 525.801 78.4492C526.574 78.7493 527.024 79.4696 527.024 80.2499V99.9372C527.024 100.597 526.638 101.258 526.059 101.618C521.489 104.319 521.424 108.82 521.424 108.881L522.261 121.365C522.326 122.265 521.746 123.046 520.845 123.346C501.277 130.008 476.303 154.317 473.535 159.479C470.819 164.599 467.635 176.202 467.013 178.65L467.131 178.794C467.063 178.914 467.063 178.974 467.063 178.974C466.976 179.336 466.763 179.664 466.473 179.925C466.101 180.345 465.55 180.629 464.974 180.667C464.122 180.724 463.269 180.244 462.907 179.531C462.899 179.518 462.89 179.505 462.882 179.491C462.875 179.479 462.868 179.467 462.861 179.454C462.522 179.874 462.048 180.594 461.505 181.854C458.252 188.874 457.439 200.753 457.439 200.873C457.303 201.893 456.354 202.733 455.134 202.733H453.711L449.78 211.553L449.373 223.073C449.305 223.433 449.237 223.733 449.034 224.033L438.935 238.792C438.867 238.912 438.732 239.032 438.596 239.152L438.596 239.152L428.022 249.112L428.565 251.032C428.768 251.752 428.497 252.472 427.819 253.012L417.313 260.931L418.94 262.551L426.531 263.211C427.345 263.271 428.022 263.691 428.361 264.351C428.7 265.011 428.632 265.731 428.158 266.331L423.617 271.971L425.176 280.071C425.244 280.191 425.244 280.311 425.244 280.431L424.837 306.77C424.837 307.31 424.566 307.85 424.091 308.21C423.685 308.57 423.075 308.75 422.397 308.69L420.025 308.51L419.414 314.69C419.279 315.71 418.33 316.49 417.11 316.49H417.042C413.45 316.43 409.79 316.43 407.824 316.61C408.163 318.71 408.095 320.029 407.689 320.929L417.042 337.369C417.246 337.849 417.313 338.329 417.178 338.809L414.806 346.429C414.534 347.269 413.653 347.869 412.637 347.869L300.191 349.908V361.788C300.191 362.868 299.174 363.768 297.954 363.768H291.922L298.903 370.848C299.31 371.208 299.513 371.808 299.445 372.348L265.541 534.2C265.509 534.428 265.446 534.657 265.345 534.866L264.062 540H170.528L162.528 536H134.028L130.928 547.366L88.7805 538H0V534H89.2195L128.072 542.634L130.972 532H163.472L171.472 536H260.5L261.035 534.126C261.022 534.072 261.01 534.016 261 533.96V533.9L294.565 372.828L285.009 363.108C284.466 362.508 284.263 361.668 284.67 360.948C285.009 360.288 285.822 359.808 286.703 359.808H295.447V347.989C295.447 346.909 296.463 346.009 297.683 346.009L410.671 343.969L412.365 338.569L402.538 321.289C402.063 320.449 402.402 319.369 403.283 318.769C403.283 318.229 403.148 317.27 402.876 315.71V315.41C402.876 314.81 403.148 314.27 403.69 313.79C404.232 313.31 405.384 312.41 414.941 312.59L415.551 306.29C415.687 305.15 416.703 304.37 417.991 304.49L420.228 304.67L420.635 280.731L418.94 271.911C418.872 271.371 419.008 270.891 419.347 270.471L422.193 266.931L417.652 266.511C417.042 266.451 416.568 266.211 416.161 265.851L412.365 262.131C412.027 261.771 411.823 261.231 411.823 260.691C411.891 260.151 412.162 259.671 412.637 259.311L423.82 250.852L423.278 249.112C423.075 248.452 423.278 247.732 423.82 247.252L435.071 236.632L444.764 222.413L445.171 211.073C445.171 210.833 445.238 210.593 445.306 210.413L449.983 200.033C450.322 199.253 451.135 198.773 452.084 198.773H452.965C453.372 194.814 454.524 186.234 457.167 180.354C458.32 177.834 460.014 174.954 462.929 174.954H463.403H463.626C463.649 174.874 463.671 174.796 463.692 174.72C463.77 174.442 463.838 174.198 463.88 174.005C463.88 173.885 463.944 173.705 464.008 173.525L464.073 173.405C464.12 173.229 464.167 173.022 464.214 172.83C464.224 172.787 464.234 172.745 464.245 172.705C464.252 172.677 464.259 172.65 464.266 172.624L464.33 172.504C465.682 167.762 467.742 161.4 469.737 157.739C472.956 151.796 497.415 127.908 517.884 120.165L517.176 109.001C517.176 108.34 517.305 102.758 522.776 98.9168V81.3903C521.939 80.7901 520.909 79.8297 520.33 78.3892C519.751 76.7686 520.008 75.0879 521.038 73.4073L523.162 69.7459V60.2624C523.162 59.7222 523.355 59.242 523.806 58.8819C524.385 58.3417 527.282 55.8208 530.05 56.481C530.886 56.6611 532.303 57.3213 532.946 59.3621C533.59 61.3428 533.847 63.8638 533.912 65.9645L536.937 63.8638C536.744 62.1831 536.744 59.242 538.675 56.3009C539.898 54.5003 542.344 34.0927 544.339 9.84366C543.824 8.64322 542.859 5.88219 544.017 3.42127C544.532 2.28085 545.755 0.840313 548.33 0.120045C548.523 0 548.652 0 548.845 0H550.776C550.969 0 551.162 0 551.291 0.0600223C553.93 0.78029 555.153 2.22083 555.668 3.36125C556.827 5.82217 555.861 8.58319 555.346 9.78364C557.342 33.9726 559.788 54.3802 561.011 56.2409C562.942 59.242 562.942 62.1831 562.748 63.8037L565.838 65.9045C565.902 63.8037 566.096 61.2828 566.739 59.3021C567.383 57.3213 568.67 56.6611 569.7 56.421C572.532 55.7607 575.365 58.2817 575.944 58.8219C576.394 59.182 576.588 59.6622 576.588 60.2024V69.6859L578.712 73.3473C579.742 75.0879 579.935 76.7686 579.42 78.3291C578.905 79.7697 577.875 80.73 576.974 81.3303V98.8568C582.509 102.758 582.574 108.52 582.574 108.76L581.866 120.045C602.335 127.788 626.794 151.616 630.013 157.619C632.201 161.7 634.518 169.203 636.192 175.025H636.643C639.41 175.025 641.02 177.906 642.114 180.427C644.624 186.309 645.718 194.892 646.105 198.854H646.941C647.843 198.854 648.615 199.334 648.937 200.114L653.378 210.498C653.443 210.678 653.507 210.918 653.507 211.159L653.893 222.503L663.098 236.728L673.783 247.352C674.298 247.832 674.491 248.552 674.298 249.213L673.783 250.953L684.403 259.417C684.854 259.777 685.112 260.257 685.176 260.797C685.176 261.337 684.983 261.877 684.661 262.238L681.056 265.959C680.67 266.319 680.22 266.559 679.64 266.619L675.328 267.039L678.031 270.581C678.353 271.001 678.482 271.481 678.417 272.021L676.808 280.844L677.194 304.793L679.318 304.613C680.541 304.493 681.507 305.274 681.636 306.414L682.215 312.716C691.291 312.536 692.385 313.437 692.9 313.917C693.415 314.397 693.672 314.937 693.672 315.537V315.838C693.415 317.398 693.286 318.358 693.286 318.899C694.123 319.499 694.445 320.579 693.994 321.42L684.661 338.706L686.27 344.108L793.571 346.149C794.73 346.149 795.695 347.049 795.695 348.13V359.954H803.999C804.835 359.954 805.608 360.434 805.93 361.094C806.316 361.815 806.123 362.655 805.608 363.255L796.532 372.979Z" fill="white" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Please add more information and some code/snippet so we can fully understand your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get only one line you need to remove a part of the d attribute. Since the drawing goes from x="0" to x="968" this is giving you a clue about what you need to remove. In your code you need to remove everything from `H0` on. Also you need to remove a bit at the begining of the d attribute. First you need to spot the `H968`. I'll transform this from a H command to a L command: Since H is a horizontal line you can take the y from the previous command. So you can change  `H968` to `LM968,531.969`, Now you remove everything from the begining to this point and change the L command to a move to M command.

You have noq a one line path AND you need to change something else. You need to recalculate the length of the path. You can do it using the getTotalLength() method. The result is 1958 and you need to replace 3904 with 1958 in the css;

```css
  .st1 {
    fill: none;
    stroke: black;
    stroke-width: 2px;
    stroke-miterlimit: 5;
  }

  .st1 {
    stroke-dasharray: 1958;
    stroke-dashoffset: 1958;
    animation: dash 3s linear forwards;
  }

  @keyframes dash {
    from {
      stroke-dashoffset: 1958;/*3904*/;
    }

    to {
      stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    }
  }
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 968 548">
  <path class="st1" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M968,536.778H946.345L934.163 528.363H827.852L808.189 510.983C808.038 510.912 807.915 510.836 807.824 510.776C807.799 510.76 807.777 510.745 807.757 510.732C807.697 510.692 807.659 510.667 807.645 510.667C807.259 510.367 807.066 509.887 807.001 509.406L791.898 372.499C791.833 371.958 792.026 371.358 792.412 370.998L799.042 363.915H793.314C792.155 363.915 791.19 363.015 791.19 361.935V350.05L684.403 348.009C683.438 348.009 682.601 347.409 682.344 346.569L680.091 338.946C679.962 338.466 680.026 337.986 680.22 337.506L689.102 321.059C688.716 320.159 688.652 318.839 688.974 316.738C687.107 316.558 683.631 316.558 680.22 316.618H680.155C678.997 316.618 678.095 315.837 677.967 314.817L677.387 308.635L675.135 308.815C674.491 308.875 673.911 308.695 673.525 308.335C673.075 307.975 672.817 307.434 672.817 306.894L672.431 280.544C672.431 280.424 672.431 280.304 672.495 280.184L673.976 272.081L669.663 266.439C669.213 265.839 669.148 265.119 669.47 264.458C669.792 263.798 670.436 263.378 671.208 263.318L678.417 262.658L679.962 261.037L669.985 253.114C669.341 252.574 669.084 251.854 669.277 251.133L669.792 249.213L659.751 239.249C659.622 239.129 659.493 239.009 659.429 238.889L649.838 224.123C649.645 223.823 649.581 223.523 649.516 223.163L649.13 211.639L645.397 202.815H644.045C642.886 202.815 641.985 201.975 641.856 200.955C641.856 200.835 641.084 188.95 637.994 181.928C637.479 180.667 637.029 179.947 636.707 179.527C636.321 180.247 635.484 180.667 634.647 180.607C633.746 180.547 632.909 179.887 632.716 179.047C632.716 179.047 632.716 178.987 632.652 178.867L632.576 178.59C631.592 174.979 628.656 164.213 626.086 159.479C623.318 154.317 598.279 130.008 578.776 123.346C577.875 123.046 577.296 122.205 577.36 121.365L578.197 108.76C578.132 108.04 577.682 104.139 573.562 101.678C572.919 101.318 572.597 100.657 572.597 99.9972V80.3099C572.597 79.5296 573.112 78.8093 573.82 78.5092H573.884C574.077 78.4492 574.978 77.969 575.236 77.1887C575.429 76.7085 575.3 76.1083 574.85 75.388L572.468 71.3065C572.275 71.0064 572.211 70.6463 572.211 70.3462V61.2228C571.631 60.8026 571.116 60.5625 570.859 60.4425V60.5025C569.893 63.5036 570.086 68.7856 570.151 69.806C570.215 70.5863 569.765 71.3065 569.057 71.7267C568.284 72.0868 567.383 72.0268 566.739 71.5466L559.144 66.3847C558.371 65.9045 558.114 65.0042 558.371 64.2239L558.38 64.187C558.479 63.7416 559.088 61.0154 557.406 58.4017C554.96 54.6203 551.935 20.1675 551.098 9.6636C551.034 9.30346 551.162 8.94333 551.291 8.64322C551.613 8.04299 552.321 6.1823 551.806 5.04188C551.613 4.62172 551.162 4.32161 550.519 4.08152H549.231C548.523 4.32161 548.137 4.62172 547.944 5.04188C547.429 6.1823 548.137 8.04299 548.459 8.64322C548.652 8.94333 548.716 9.30346 548.652 9.6636C547.558 23.1086 544.726 54.7404 542.344 58.4017C540.477 61.2228 541.378 64.2239 541.378 64.2239C541.636 65.0042 541.314 65.9045 540.606 66.3847L532.946 71.6066C532.303 72.0868 531.401 72.1468 530.629 71.7867C529.857 71.4266 529.47 70.6463 529.535 69.926C529.599 68.8456 529.792 63.6237 528.827 60.6226V60.5025C528.798 60.5159 528.765 60.5309 528.729 60.5474C528.44 60.6785 527.932 60.9096 527.475 61.2828V70.2261C527.475 70.5863 527.411 70.8864 527.217 71.1865L524.772 75.268C524.385 75.9883 524.257 76.5885 524.385 77.1287C524.707 77.909 525.737 78.4492 525.801 78.4492C526.574 78.7493 527.024 79.4696 527.024 80.2499V99.9372C527.024 100.597 526.638 101.258 526.059 101.618C521.489 104.319 521.424 108.82 521.424 108.881L522.261 121.365C522.326 122.265 521.746 123.046 520.845 123.346C501.277 130.008 476.303 154.317 473.535 159.479C470.819 164.599 467.635 176.202 467.013 178.65L467.131 178.794C467.063 178.914 467.063 178.974 467.063 178.974C466.976 179.336 466.763 179.664 466.473 179.925C466.101 180.345 465.55 180.629 464.974 180.667C464.122 180.724 463.269 180.244 462.907 179.531C462.899 179.518 462.89 179.505 462.882 179.491C462.875 179.479 462.868 179.467 462.861 179.454C462.522 179.874 462.048 180.594 461.505 181.854C458.252 188.874 457.439 200.753 457.439 200.873C457.303 201.893 456.354 202.733 455.134 202.733H453.711L449.78 211.553L449.373 223.073C449.305 223.433 449.237 223.733 449.034 224.033L438.935 238.792C438.867 238.912 438.732 239.032 438.596 239.152L438.596 239.152L428.022 249.112L428.565 251.032C428.768 251.752 428.497 252.472 427.819 253.012L417.313 260.931L418.94 262.551L426.531 263.211C427.345 263.271 428.022 263.691 428.361 264.351C428.7 265.011 428.632 265.731 428.158 266.331L423.617 271.971L425.176 280.071C425.244 280.191 425.244 280.311 425.244 280.431L424.837 306.77C424.837 307.31 424.566 307.85 424.091 308.21C423.685 308.57 423.075 308.75 422.397 308.69L420.025 308.51L419.414 314.69C419.279 315.71 418.33 316.49 417.11 316.49H417.042C413.45 316.43 409.79 316.43 407.824 316.61C408.163 318.71 408.095 320.029 407.689 320.929L417.042 337.369C417.246 337.849 417.313 338.329 417.178 338.809L414.806 346.429C414.534 347.269 413.653 347.869 412.637 347.869L300.191 349.908V361.788C300.191 362.868 299.174 363.768 297.954 363.768H291.922L298.903 370.848C299.31 371.208 299.513 371.808 299.445 372.348L265.541 534.2C265.509 534.428 265.446 534.657 265.345 534.866L264.062 540H170.528L162.528 536H134.028L130.928 547.366L88.7805 538H0" fill="white" />

</svg>
```